# How do I write matrices inside of brackets (i.e., matrices in a set)

Tags: matrices

I'm pretty new to this, and I feel like this is pretty simple but I just can't seem to get how to do it!

I want to type a set of matrices for a basis of a subspace. For example, if I have the basis `{(1,0,-1),(0,2,3),(1,1,1)}`, I'd like to type this as a set of column vectors. Is there a way for me to do this?

Comment: Try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
(1,0,-1)    \\
(0,2,3)     \\
(1,1,1)     
\end{bmatrix} 
\]
\end{document}`. Does it gives what you like to obtain? Welcome to the site!

Comment: @Zarko - Your solution would write the basis vectors as row vectors, right? Maybe add transpose operators after each row vector?

Comment: @Mico, I didn't understood question well, so with comment I ask, what OP like to have.  Transpose operators are very sensible: `\begin{bmatrix} (1,0,-1)^T\\ (0,2,3)^T \\ (1,1,1)^T \end{bmatrix}`. Thank you for pointing me to this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you want to use round parentheses to delimit each column vector and curly braces to denote that the three column vectors form a set, you could proceed using three `pmatrix` environments enclosed in `\left\{` and `\right\}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'pmatrix' environment
\begin{document}
\[
\left\{
\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ -1 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 2\\  3 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\  1 \end{pmatrix}
\right\}
\] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want square brackets instead of round parentheses to enclose the column vectors, use `bmatrix` instead of `pmatrix`.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two other solutions: one uses the `Bmatrix` environment, the other (semantically more satisfying) defines a `\set` command, based on the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools`. Its  starred version adjusts the size of the braces to its contents. An optional argument `[\big]`, `\Big]`, &c., allows fine-tuning of the size of the braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} %

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\set}\{\}
\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\\ -1 \end{pmatrix},
    \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2\\ 3 \end{pmatrix},
    \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
  \end{Bmatrix}
\]

\[
  \set*{%
    \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ -1 \end{pmatrix},
    \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 2\\ 3 \end{pmatrix},
    \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
  }%
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article} 

 \usepackage{mathtools}

  \begin{document}
 \begin{align}  
  \left\{\left[\begin{array}{c}
   1\\
   0\\
   -1
   \end{array}
  \right],\quad \left[\begin{array}{c}
   1\\
   1\\
   1
  \end{array}
  \right], \quad \left[\begin{array}{c}
   0\\
   2\\
   3
   \end{array}
  \right]
  \right\}
 \end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use an `align` environment for a single-line equation?